# how do I fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a game with html & javascript and if you would click on a
`<input type="button" name="house" value="House:50€" onclick="house()"`

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr2" id="sqr2" value=" " onClick="">
```

and

```
function house(){            
if(sqr2.value == ' '){
var sqr2 = document.getElementById("sqr2");
var txtNumber = document.getElementById("Money");
var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) - 50;
var sqr2huis = "House";
Geld.value = newNumber;
sqr2.value = sqr2house;   
}
    }
```

the thing I want to do is that if you would buy a house and then buy it again it won't spend your money but it won't it gives this error message:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at house
at HTMLInputElement.onclick
house 
onclick

does anyone know a way to fix this or tell me what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Looks like there is not HTML element with the id `Money`

Comment: i do have an element with the id money     <input type="button" id="Money" name="Money" value="50">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to define `sqr2` before you check its value:

```js
function house(){            
  var sqr2 = document.getElementById("sqr2");
  if (sqr2.value == ' '){
    var txtNumber = document.getElementById("Money");
    var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) - 50;
    var sqr2huis = "House";
    Geld.value = newNumber;
    sqr2.value = sqr2house;   
  }
}
```